# Hibernate execution delay

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

The name of the post may be odd but i don't know how to call this.

Every time i interact with the database (MYSQL) i get this output then the execution beings.

Theses messages causes delay till the execution happens and i hate it really. how i could fix that and make the execution start immediately?

```
Feb 12, 2014 7:37:04 PM org.hibernate.annotations.common.Version <clinit>
    INFO: HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {4.0.2.Final}
    Feb 12, 2014 7:37:04 PM org.hibernate.Version logVersion
    INFO: HHH000412: Hibernate Core {4.2.2.Final}
    Feb 12, 2014 7:37:04 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Environment <clinit>
    INFO: HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
    Feb 12, 2014 7:37:04 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Environment buildBytecodeProvider
    INFO: HHH000021: Bytecode provider name : javassist
    Feb 12, 2014 7:37:04 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration configure
    INFO: HHH000043: Configuring from resource: /main/hibernate.cfg.xml
    Feb 12, 2014 7:37:04 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration getConfigurationInputStream
    INFO: HHH000040: Configuration resource: /main/hibernate.cfg.xml
    Feb 12, 2014 7:37:05 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration doConfigure
    INFO: HHH000041: Configured SessionFactory: 
    Feb 12, 2014 7:37:05 PM  org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl configure
    INFO: HHH000402: Using Hibernate built-in connection pool (not for production use!)
    Feb 12, 2014 7:37:05 PM  org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl configure
    INFO: HHH000115: Hibernate connection pool size: 20
    Feb 12, 2014 7:37:05 PM  org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl configure
    INFO: HHH000006: Autocommit mode: false
    Feb 12, 2014 7:37:05 PM  org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl configure
    INFO: HHH000401: using driver [com.mysql.jdbc.Driver] at URL   [jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/testing]
    Feb 12, 2014 7:37:05 PM   org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl configure
    INFO: HHH000046: Connection properties: {user=root, password=****}
    Feb 12, 2014 7:37:06 PM org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect <init>
    INFO: HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
    Feb 12, 2014 7:37:07 PM   org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.TransactionFactoryInitiator initiateService
INFO: HHH000399: Using default transaction strategy (direct JDBC transactions)
    Feb 12, 2014 7:37:07 PM org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.ASTQueryTranslatorFactory <init>
    INFO: HHH000397: Using ASTQueryTranslatorFactory
    Feb 12, 2014 7:37:07 PM org.hibernate.validator.internal.util.Version <clinit>
    INFO: HV000001: Hibernate Validator 5.0.2.Final
    Feb 12, 2014 7:37:09 PM org.hibernate.search.Version <clinit>
    INFO: HSEARCH000034: Hibernate Search 4.3.0.Final
    Feb 12, 2014 7:37:09 PM org.hibernate.search.impl.ConfigContext getLuceneMatchVersion
    WARN: HSEARCH000075: Configuration setting hibernate.search.lucene_version was not     specified, using LUCENE_CURRENT.
    Feb 12, 2014 7:37:11 PM org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryRegistry addSessionFactory
WARN: HHH000277: Could not bind factory to JNDI
org.hibernate.service.jndi.JndiException: Error parsing JNDI name []
    at org.hibernate.service.jndi.internal.JndiServiceImpl.parseName(JndiServiceImpl.java:92)
    at org.hibernate.service.jndi.internal.JndiServiceImpl.bind(JndiServiceImpl.java:108)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryRegistry.addSessionFactory(SessionFactoryRegistry.java:89)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:480)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1769)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1840)
    at controller.DAO.<clinit>(DAO.java:57)
    at main.Main.main(Main.java:92)
    Caused by: javax.naming.NoInitialContextException: Need to specify class name in   environment or system property, or as an applet parameter, or in an application resource     file:  java.naming.factory.initial
    at javax.naming.spi.NamingManager.getInitialContext(Unknown Source)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.getDefaultInitCtx(Unknown Source)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.getURLOrDefaultInitCtx(Unknown Source)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.getNameParser(Unknown Source)
    at       org.hibernate.service.jndi.internal.JndiServiceImpl.parseName(JndiServiceImpl.java:86)
    ... 7 more</code>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what your seeing is hibernate initializing.
by looking at it it looks like core hibernate is up in 3 seconds (7:37:04 - 7:37:07) and you have an extra 4 seconds for initializing hibernate search and validator. are you using hibernate search and validator? perhaps you could disable them in your configuration.

Comment: Yeah, actually i am using them. So, this is normal execution and i should not worry about it right?

Comment: if you need those features than you need to pay the time cost of initializing them :-) whats your use case/application ? perhaps you can avoid repeated re-initializations

Comment: It is a certification management system. in our company we calibrate sensors and this system will manage certificates issuing because the data is huge and accuracy is very important.

Comment: @imorad87 - and do you need to launch it anew every time? if you split it into a server component that talks to the database (using hibernate) and is always on and a client component that you launch every time and sends data to the server your delay will be much smaller.

Comment: The problem is that it is a stand alone application. the database server and the client will be in the same machine. I will be using threads much to deal with the interactions with the database for the UI doesn't hang

Comment: @imorad87 - you could initialize hibernate in a background thread - your app will appear to start much faster :-)

Comment: Yup, i have done that but this also has its drawbacks since i have to redraw or refresh the UI to reflect the changes.